# Comparing max and min across groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with nested groups (produced using `summarize` in `dyplr`). Each case contains 2 groups. For each of the two groups, I have a maximum value of another variable and a minimum.  So for each case, I have 2 max and 2 min values.  What I am trying to do is create a new indicator variable that is coded 1 under specific conditions across groups.  Here's some code that produces sample data that look like mine:

```
data <- expand.grid(groupID=1:2, caseID=1:3)
data$max <- rnorm(nrow(data))
data$min <- rnorm(nrow(data))
```

So, the basic data look like this:

```
  > data
  groupID caseID         max         min
1       1      1 -0.17317875 -0.65772183
2       2      1 -0.32221584  1.39254577
3       1      2  0.33535437 -1.55013998
4       2      2 -0.03950875  1.24181830
5       1      3  1.00759879 -1.29394582
6       2      3  0.28469228 -0.03454565
```

What I want is an indicator, unique to each caseID, that is generated by comparing values across groupID.  Say, if the the max of group 1 is greater than the min of group 2:

```
  groupID caseID         max         min  newVar
1       1      1 -0.17317875 -0.65772183      0
2       2      1 -0.32221584  1.39254577      0
3       1      2  0.33535437 -1.55013998      0
4       2      2 -0.03950875  1.24181830      0
5       1      3  1.00759879 -1.29394582      1
6       2      3  0.28469228 -0.03454565      1
```

Comment: Your random data doesn't have max > min, generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset your columns as vectors within groups like this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(caseID) %>%
  mutate(newVar = max[groupID == 1] > min[groupID == 2])
```

Comment: This did it.  I knew it was a fairly simple answer, and I was in that frustrating space of being 90% of the way there.  Thanks!!